# Crash : org.chromium.android_webview.AwDataDirLock.b

Tags: webview

We are facing below type of crashes.

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Using WebView from more than one process at once with the same data directory is not supported. https://crbug.com/558377 : Current process [Package Name] (pid 28046), lock owner  unknown
at org.chromium.android_webview.AwDataDirLock.b(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-626110530:201)
at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.j(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-626110530:15)
at com.android.webview.chromium.M.e(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-626110530:198)
at WV.JZ.run(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-626110530:8)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7663)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)

Image : [Crash Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5RDu.png)

I checked my app and I am not using any web view but we are facing this issue after adding the google consent form.